# Computing Binomial Distribution Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How do I compute $E(2^{X}3^{(1-X)})$ given $X \sim Bin(1,p)$. Note that $X = 1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean that $X$ is an indicator random variable with probability of success equal $p$? In that case, if $X=1$ the expectation equals 2 and if $X=0$ it equals 3.  As the first occurs with probability $p$, the final answer is $2p + 3(1-p) = 3-p$

Comment: Sorry, I meant X distributes to a binomial with (n = 1, p = p) (X ~ Bin(1,p))

Comment: so, this is an indicator random variable